# What are the chances for firestore to generate two identical random keys?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a project and firestore random keys where kind of important in this scenario, so my question is, what are the chances for firebase firestore or the real-time database to generate two or more identical random variables?

Answer (score 4):

According to this blog link : [**The 2^120 Ways to Ensure Unique Identifiers**](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html)

### How Push IDs are Generated

> Push IDs are string identifiers that are generated client-side. They
>   are a combination of a timestamp and some random bits. The timestamp
>   ensures they are ordered chronologically, and the random bits ensure
>   that each ID is unique, even if thousands of people are creating push
>   IDs at the same time.

### What's in a Push ID?

> A push ID contains 120 bits of information. The first 48 bits are a
>   timestamp, which both reduces the chance of collision and allows
>   consecutively created push IDs to sort chronologically. The timestamp
>   is followed by 72 bits of randomness, which ensures that even two
>   people creating push IDs at the exact same millisecond are extremely
>   unlikely to generate identical IDs. One caveat to the randomness is
>   that in order to preserve chronological ordering if a client creates
>   multiple push IDs in the same millisecond, we just 'increment' the
>   random bits by one.
>
> To turn our 120 bits of information (timestamp + randomness) into an
>   ID that can be used as a Firebase key, we basically base64 encode it
>   into ASCII characters, but we use a modified base64 alphabet that
>   ensures the IDs will still sort correctly when ordered
>   lexicographically (since Firebase keys are ordered lexicographically).

Answer (score 3):

While Gastón Saillén's answer is 100% correct regarding the pushed key from Firebase realtime database, I'll try to add a few more details.

When using DatabaseReference's [push()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.html#push()) method, it generates a key that has a time component, so basically two events can theoretically take place within the same millisecond but there is an astronomically small chance that two users can generate a key in the exact same moment and with the exact same randomness. Please also note, that these keys are generated entirely on the client without consultation Firebase server. If you are interested, here is the [algorithm that generates those keys](https://gist.github.com/mikelehen/3596a30bd69384624c11). In the end, I can tell you that I haven't heard of a person who reported a problem with key collisions so far.

So unlike Fireabase realtime database keys, Cloud Firestore ids are actually purely random. There's no time component included. This built-in generator for unique ids that is used in Firestore when you call CollectionReference's [add()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/CollectionReference.html#add(java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%3E)) methods or CollectionReference's [document()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/CollectionReference.html#document()) method without passing any parameters, generates random and highly unpredictable ids, which prevents hitting certain hotspots in the backend infrastructure. That's also the reason why there is no order, if you check the documents in a collection in the Firebase console. The collisions of ids in this case is incredibly unlikely and you can/should assume they'll be completely unique. That's what they were designed for. Regarding the algorithm, you can check Frank van Puffelen's answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54008556/5246885). So you don't have to be concerned about this ids.