# Is it OK to duplicate document Ids in different Firestore collections?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

Suppose I have a collection called `savedGamesFull`. Whenever a document is created in this collection, it receives the Firebase-generated ID; I then reuse this ID and give it to another document in a parallel collection `savedGamesLight`.

In another example, for each document in `players` collection, there would be a document with the same id in `playerPublicProfiles` and `playerStats` collections.

Basically, all this naming method does is that it saves a few lines of code here and there, and there is no need to keep the `userId` field in those parallel documents.

But after reading about [hotspotting](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/best-practices#hotspots) (although it doesn't seem to apply here) I got concerned that there may be issues with this naming.

So are there any downsides to having the same document IDs in several different collections?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it OK to duplicate document IDs in different Firestore collections?

Yes. It is actually a quite common practice when it comes to identifying users across your application, no matter what the collection is.

> I then reuse this id and give it to another document in a parallel collection savedGamesLight.

In the NoSQL world, it's always a good practice to [denormalize data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54258303/what-is-denormalization-in-firebase-cloud-firestore). This means that it totally makes sense to display data from lighter documents rather than from heavier documents.

> But after reading about hot-spotting (although it doesn't seem to apply here) I got concerned that there may be issues with this naming.

Hot-spotting doesn't refer to having the same document IDs in multiple collections or sub-collections. It's about having [sequential document IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68910158/5246885).

> So are there any downsides to having the same document ids in several different collections?

Not at all. It's quite normal.

Answer (score 1):

You can use same document ID in multiple collection. Its pretty useful for one-one mapping e.g. using user's UID in *users* collection (stores private information) and *profiles* collection (stores public information).

Because you know ID of the document, you can fetch documents from all collections (*players*, *playerPublicProfiles* and *playerStats*) at once with [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and don't have to fetch player document, read public profile document ID and then fetch the profile.